# What's wrong with my code? My background doesn't cover the full page

Tags: html, css

My background image doesn't seem to be covering the whole page. [Link to site](http://openworldmc.github.io/)

As you can see in the image below, there's a black bar at the bottom.

Could someone please look at my code and tell me what I've done wrong? I've tried many things.

All code can be found on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/openworldmc/openworldmc.github.io).

[image: image of issue]

---

CSS attributes in use:

```
background-image: url(img/sc1.png);
padding-top: 40px;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
min-height: 100vh;
height: auto;
width: 100vw;
max-width: 100%;
```

Comment: black bar at the bottom - body { background-color: #130f0e;}

Comment: I've tried various browsers and I can't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
.item {
   height: auto;
}
```

to

```
.item {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your `.desc` class set margin bottom to 0, so change `margin:40px auto`

```
.desc {
    /* margin bottom to 0 */
    margin: 40px auto 0;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    font-size: 2vw;
    background-color: rgba(19, 15, 14, 0.6);
    width: 80%;
}
```

and on `.item` class set padding bottom to keep space between the transparent black box of `.desc` and bottom of the page:

```
.item{
    ...
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare background-image on body.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp
or add to `body` `class="s1"` and change `.s1` to

```
    .s1 {
        background-image: url(img/sc1.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
    }
```

Then delete in class `.item` `display:none;`

And then you need to change the `.desc` class because its margin and padding creates another black bar.

EDIT: Just put `padding:0px;` in the `.desc` class and it will work.
And don't forget to change `div class="item s1"` in the html file to  `div class="item"`

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the right way to solve this problem, but the black bar goes away if you apply the background to the html element instead of that item element.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: url(img/sc1.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set your background to match the height of the viewport, but your content has exceeded the viewport height. If you temp removed the desc you will be able to witness this happening. Also the desc has a 20px padding all around. No need to have 20px on bottom. Try padding:15px 15px 5px;

If you want to use viewport only then you need to work to remove the scrollbar. If you want to keep the scrollbar then you need remove the vh height setting.